# Android Dev - R.layout.main , Variable 'R' cannot be resolved

Tags: android

We are new to Android and we are trying to develop a new application. We installed all the basic setup of Android. We tried to run the Android Sample projects in Eclipse. But while to compile the following lines and a few other lines that uses the variable 'R' throws up an error.

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

'R cannot be resolved to a variable'. I do not understand what is causing the error. Anyone help me out in this issue.

Comment: was your problem finally solve ?

Answer (score 7):

check that the import for R class is not

```
import com.android.R;
```

and you should make it

```
import yourpackagename.R;
```

then recompile

Answer (score 3):

Please try to clean the project, and try compiling again.

If not solved, refer to [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 2):

If you have 64 bit Linux platform without ia32 libraries, then this problem could also occur. It took me quite some time to pin this one down, seeing that the problem is not clearly linked with the inability to execute 32 bit code.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the import part `import com.android.R.layout` instead of `com.android.R`

Answer (score 1):

In my case i forgot to re-install the SDK. When you re-install your operating system, you should re-extract (re-install) your SDK Zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you have your android libraries mapped correctly in the settings for Eclipse (if you are using eclipse to develop).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your resorce name (for example template.xml) has ONLY small caps letters.

Answer (score 0):

import com.packagename.R* will worl

Answer (score 0):

Change import to

```
import yourpackagename.R;
```

If error is still there then

```
go to gen folder->packagename->R.java
```

and remove error line some times it gave error on drawable files.

Answer (score 0):

**setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)**

Change the SDK and delete the project and create new ... it will definitely work!