# Cannot find R.layout.activity_main in main activity.java

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an app, and have started working on main screen design but I am not able to test my app. When I want to test the app it suddenly stop all the time and error showing in catlog in the line

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

I have attached the screenshots in this question also.

[image: main activity]

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: What is this error?

Comment: Try to clean and build the project

Comment: build -> clean project.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045118/cannot-find-r-layout-activity-main).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I invite to you to clean project and rebuild again, you have the [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581254/4385913) here.

And remove those imports that contains `R` in your project.

> import vibhor.dev.eat24.R;
>
> import vibhor.dev.eat24.R.layout;

I see you have this :

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

Change it to :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

This is problem of your library, take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079801/4385913), try it, if it does not work.. just change the library.

Comment: i did the same as you said whn i clean project R got red then during rebuild it was not red but when i run the app ,it is giving me the same error :(  https://imgur.com/a/LoRCO   https://imgur.com/a/Vfpwq

Comment: Clean project and build?

Comment: ya i did that ,can i send you code or by any method ,i need to solve it quickly :(

Comment: make a screenshoot of logcat please

Comment: move a little bit to the right I need to see the error clear

Comment: Can you post the `activity_main.xml` please?

Comment: Show me your build.gradle please, make sure you have this implemenation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5';

Comment: build.gradle(project)-https://justpaste.it/1eaih  build.gradle(module:app)-https://justpaste.it/1eaij

Comment: Change `compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'` to `implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'`

Comment: i did this but the app is stil not running :(  https://imgur.com/a/BZMnB

Comment: yes i checked and did that but got this error at this point ..i didn't understand what it is saying https://imgur.com/a/ux7Zk

Comment: If there is an update of dependencies then i dont think that we should use 2.3.3 in place of 3.0.1

Comment: Hey,i just solved this to degrade the gradle build version to 2.3.3  :)

Comment: thank you so much :)   but just tell me 1 thing will get problem in some devices due to gradle degradation???

Answer (score 0):

try that solution:

check that the import for R class is not import com.android.R;

and you should make it import yourpackagename.R, then recompile

if it works, your answer has already been replied **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145299/android-dev-r-layout-main-variable-r-cannot-be-resolved)**.

Comment: try to check your gradle configurations, clean the code and then recompile your project.

Answer (score 0):

R.java is automatically generated on build, and it is automatically imported so you don't have to import it explicitly.

Try this:

1. delete **generated** sub folder in your app folder since R.java is in one of its sub folders

[image]

2. rebuild your project and **generated** folder will be generated again

Comment: i did this but stll app is not running  :(

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Could you please post your logcat window. I would like to see the actual exception you are getting. And your activity_main xml layout file as well.

Answer (score 0):

vibhor vibhoti -- your problem is that you are using 
(  view  ) tag with v small in your activity_main.xml 
change it to (  View  ) with Capital  V .. that is the SOLUTION